# AWS create tags for instances launched in ECS Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create tags for EC2 instances from userdata script after the instance is launched using a cloudformation. The ec2 instances are part of an ECS AutoScaling group. The ECS ASG cloudformation is creating the the instances in the given VPCZoneIdentifiers. The tags I need on these instances depend on the AZ they are launched into, so they are kind of dynamic. I haven't been able to find any way to make this, i.e. look at the AZ the ECS ASG will launch the current instance in and add appropriate tag, happen in the cloudformation. So my second idea is to add tags from inside the userdata script. I am basically using the instance metadata and create-tags tool inside cloudinit script to add tags. I am able to get the instance-id during cloudinit but when trying to create tags on the instance id, I get instance id does not exist error. Am not sure what's happening here.

Does AWS block operations on instances which running the userdata script? Any suggestions how I can add the tags? I have some custom code in the end of userdata script which depends on these tags. Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I do this all the time no problem. Can you post the userdata script?

Comment: @RodrigoM thanks, it's working now. Retried it and it worked just fine, weird.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can add the tags by getting it from created instance in cloud formation itself.

Please try statement(YAML)

Ex. `AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt '<Your_instance>.AvailabilityZone'`